# How to print only the matching line in file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import re
shakes = open("output.txt", "r")
for line in shakes:
    if re.match(r'.*(\w*Daemon\w*).*', line):
        print(line)
        break
    else:
        print("none")
```

output:

```
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
none
local1.crit: Aug 23 09:08:42 abvlab_ confd[860]: - Daemon n_7 died
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. You need to use [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). I [edit]ed the question for you. What exactly are you having difficulty with? I mean can't you just remove the `else` clause?

Comment: Just get rid of `print("none")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do for example:

```
matching_shakes = list(filter(lambda line: re.match(regex, line), shakes))
```

Comment: import re
shks = open("output.txt", "r") matching_shakes = list(filter(lambda line: re.match(r'.*(\w*Daemon vdaemon\w*).*', line), shks))
for line in matching_shakes:
 if re.match(matching_shakes, line):
 else:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/auto/pysw/cel63/python64/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 172, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "/auto/pysw/cel63/python64/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/re.py", line 289, in _compile
    p, loc = _cache[type(pattern), pattern, flags]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: matching_shakes is a list, you can just do print(matching_shakes[0])

Comment: new to python sorry